# Angularjs export to excel not working in IE

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, excel, export-to-excel

I want to export my data to excel or pdf but then it's not working in IE. I tried to export it in Chrome and its working fine.
But most of the people who'll use my project are using internet explorer. Can anyone take a look on my codes and maybe suggest me what to do ?

Here's my Angular function :

```
          scope.exportData = function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate();
            var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"

            });
            saveAs(blob, "Report_" + d + ".xls");
        };

        scope.exportDataItems = function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate();
            var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportablePRItems').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"

            });
            saveAs(blob, "Items_"+ d +".xls");
        };


    }]);
```

I am actually using [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/).

Comment: What version of IE is this not working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be of a little help. :)

```
  scope.exportDataNew = function () {
                var d = new Date();
                var mont = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
                if (typeof scope.filter_fromDate == 'undefined') {
                    scope.filter_fromDate = mont[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate().toString() + ", " + d.getFullYear().toString();

                }
                if (typeof scope.filter_toDate == 'undefined') {
                    scope.filter_toDate = mont[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate().toString() + ", " + d.getFullYear().toString();
                }
                if (typeof scope.EntityID == 'undefined') {
                    scope.EntityID = "";
                }
                if (typeof scope.DepartmentID == 'undefined') {
                    scope.DepartmentID = "";
                }
                location.href = 'ExportExcel?from=' + scope.filter_fromDate + '&to=' + scope.filter_toDate + '&EntityID=' + scope.EntityID + '&DepartmentID=' + scope.DepartmentID;
            };
            scope.exportData = function () {
                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + date.getDate();
                var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"

                });
                saveAs(blob, "Report_" + d + ".xls");
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use alasql. It works with IE9

https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Angular.js

Change xlsx to xls.

Answer (score 2):

We can implement export to excel using JSONCSVConverter
Steps involved

1. JSONtoCSVConverter javascript file.
2. JSON Data
3. Jquery

This line is important
 **JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Blog Report", true);**

1st parameter accepts data
 2nd parameter we specify the file name
 3rd paramter we spcecify whether we need label

Reference

[Blog](http://www.prathapkudupublog.com/2015/10/excel-export-from-json.html)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/amMRNeLfbLB9NHe1dOaW?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internet explorer download</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h3><u>Enter JSON data</u></h3>
        <div class="mydiv">
    <textarea cols="100" rows="15" class="txtarea" id="txt">[{"Blog Name":"PrathapKudupusBlog","Date":"30 Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Type":"Technical","Author"
:"Prathap Kudupu"},
{"Blog Name":"ABCBlog","Date":"30 Jul 2011 09:24 AM","Type":"Technical","Author"
:"ABC"},
{"Blog Name":"XYZBlog","Date":"30 Jul 2011 09:24 AM","Type":"Technical","Author"
:"XYZ"}]</textarea>      <br>
        <h3><u>Click below button to download <strong>CSV</strong> file for internet explorer and other browsers</u></h3>
        <br>
        <button class="download">Download CSV</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var data = $('#txt').val();
        if(data == '')
            return;

        JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Blog report", true);
    });
});

 function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData,title, ShowLabel) {
            var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
            var CSV = '';
            if (ShowLabel) {
                var row = "";
                for (var index in arrData[0]) {
                    row += index + ',';
                }
                row = row.slice(0, -1);
                CSV += row + '\r\n';
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                var row = "";
                for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                    var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
                    row += arrValue + ',';
                }
                row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
                CSV += row + '\r\n';
            }
            if (CSV == '') {
                growl.error("Invalid data");
                return;
            }
            var fileName = title;
            if (msieversion()) {
                var IEwindow = window.open();
                IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
                IEwindow.document.close();
                IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
                IEwindow.close();
            } else {
                var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = uri;
                link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                link.download = fileName + ".csv";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }
        function msieversion() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
            if (msie != -1 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number 
            {
                return true;
            } else { // If another browser, 
                return false;
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: Issue using alasql it gives a warning message before opening the excel file